useEffect not showing error for non existent event listener in cleanup
So as per documentation in React, the initial state of the below code of canMove is true. I changed it to false.
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleMove(e) {
      setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
    }
    if (canMove)
      window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);
  }, [canMove]);

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={canMove}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setCanMove(e.target.checked)
            }
          } 
        />
        The dot is allowed to move
      </label>
      <hr />
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        opacity: 0.6,
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        left: -20,
        top: -20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      }} />
    </>
  );
}

So after first render, useEffect runs but adding event listener to "pointermove" is dependent on canMove which is now false and hence no event listener is added. Now if we click the checkbox, canMove is true this triggers the useEffect again, and the cleanup should run first. But there is no handlemove function added to pointer move previously. So this line should give error logically?

It's not an error to enqueue removal of an event listener... if it exists then it will be removed, otherwise, it's ignored. See EventTarget: removeEventListener:

Calling removeEventListener() with arguments that do not identify
any currently registered event listener on the EventTarget has no
effect.

This means your current/initial code is ok, no error should be thrown because an event listener wasn't added previously.

so why does this piece of code doesn't work.
const [canMove, setCanMove] = useState(true);   useEffect(() => {     if(!canMove)     window.removeEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);     if (canMove){       function handleMove(e) {         setPosition({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });       }       window.addEventListener('pointermove', handleMove);     }       }, [canMove]);
the rest of the code is same. Here useEffect runs and adds handleMove to pointermove.

When canMove changes to false, the first condition runs, new handleMove is still not defined rather earlier handleMove is already added to pointermove so why does removing it gives error.

@Indra Sorry, are you seeing some error? In your post you said there was none but you were expecting one for some reason. In your first comment though you are trying to reference handleMove before it is declared, and in fact, it's declared in a different javascript scope, i.e. the if-block's scope. It'd probably work if you moved the handleMove declaration to the top of the useEffect hook callback function like it is in your post.

Yeah in my first comment. I just removed the cleanup and added both inside useEffect setup. My idea was if the handleMove is added to the event listener when the useEffect runs initially, and then canMove becomes false, then it goes to the first if block and encounters to remove handleMove which is already added to the pointermove. I expect this to work as when canMove is true it doesn't goes to the if block where handleMove is defined. And I am asking JS to just remove the handleMove function which was previously added.

@Indra That version is flawed since you are now omitting the cleanup function to remove the event listener when the component unmounts and before applying any new effects. I don't think there is any issue with the code you have in your post. Are you implying you have some issue with it or it's not working in some way as you are expecting? It adds the event listener when canMove is true, and returns a cleanup function to remove any added listener.

no I am not referring to the code in the question but this

@Indra Ok, that's the problem I described where you are trying to reference handleMove before it is declared. Moving handleMove to the top fixes that issue, but then the removal still doesn't work for the other reason I described. That said, when I edit that sandbox to the code you have in your post the UI works as I think you are intending. When the "can move" checkbox is de-selected the dot sticks and doesn't move, and when it's checked, the dot follows the mouse.

But moving handleMove to the top doesn't fixes the issue at all. Can you share a link.

@Indra I'm not very familiar with stackblitz, but here's your edited code in a running codesandbox. Like I said though, moving handleMove to the top of the effect callback only fixes the reference issue, there's still the issue of effect cleanup to remove any previously added listeners that doesn't work. Using a proper returned cleanup function addresses that, e.g. the code in your post. Am I misunderstanding your post/question?

Got it. But suppose the cleanup is not present: (In my SB code)
-initially canMove is true=>listener handleMove got added to poinetermove.
-for subsequent renders(only due to setPosition) no code of useEffect runs.
-now canMove changes to false => no cleanup in code=>setup starts running=>if block when canMove is false runs=>handleMove is still not defined in this render(as control does not reaches that particular if block)=> now we try to remove the existing added handleMove. - why this doesn't work?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
